# 'pyrcc5' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am working from my laptop here in school, I've moved files from my PC at home to my laptop and when I try to run things I get this error:

```
'pyrcc5' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
```

operable program or batch file.

Code:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You had to use `py -m pip install ...`. That means that the Python commands folders (where pip has installed `pyrcc5.exe` is not in your PATH.

You can ask the Python installation path with:

```
py --list-paths
```

and get something like:

```
Installed Pythons found by py Launcher for Windows
 -3.10-64       C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe *
 -3.9-64        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python39_64\python.exe
 ...
```

The commands are available in the `Scripts` subfolder, so for example for the first installation the full path would be:

```
C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts\pyrcc5
```

Alternatively you can add the folder to the Windows path for the current session:

```
PATH C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts\;%PATH%
```

Comment: I did the command and got 
`(tfod) C:\Users\User\Desktop\Electronics Project\Project's DL\DL\TFODCourse>py --list-paths
Installed Pythons found by py Launcher for Windows
 -3.9-64        C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe *
`

Comment: I have this path: `C:\Users\User\Desktop\Electronics Project\Project's DL\DL\TFODCourse\tfod\Scripts\pyrcc5.exe` This one should I use?- This is in the VENV

Comment: @David: when you *activate* a venv, you automatically get an updated PATH. You should **never** use the `py` launcher with a venv. Either your venv was not correctly set up, or you failed to activate it.